# Is it possible to check if the user is logged in in php script which has embedded yii2?

Tags: yii2

I put a custom script in main yii2 installation directory and I need to know in this script if user is logged in main yii2 app(called frontend).
I use this code

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';

$yiiConfig = require __DIR__ . '/../config/yii/web.php';
new yii\web\Application($yiiConfig); // Do NOT call run() here
```

from:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-integration#using-yii-in-others

And use this code

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
```

but it throws that app variable is not available. I tried other combinations but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to store the instance of `yii\web\Application` in some variable. Then You can use that variable instead of `Yii::$app`.

```php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';

$yiiConfig = require __DIR__ . '/../config/yii/web.php';
$app = new yii\web\Application($yiiConfig); // Do NOT call run() here

echo $app->user->identity->id;
```

Btw the `Yii::$app` is set in `yii\base\Application::__construct`. `Yii::$app` should be usable even if you don't call `run()` method. Your problem might have some deeper cause.

Comment: it doesnt/works without explicite $app variable. The problem was that yii must be set/loaded before my script(which touched session). But thanks!